# Must declare the scalar variable "@LocationId"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.vwAlarmAssetGroupLocationReport
WHERE (LocationID = CAST(COALESCE(@LocationId, LocationId) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) 
       OR TopLocationId = CAST(COALESCE(@LocationId, TopLocationId) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))
  AND DateCreated BETWEEN '2018-10-23 AND 2018-10-25'
  AND AssetGroupId = '8E99BAFB-739A-E411-B54B-40F2E9985B7A'
ORDER BY DateCreated
```

keep getting this error message when I try to run my report in SQL Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please edit the question to retag it accordingly.

Comment: In which context you run that query?  From a stored procedure, from a console application, ...?

Comment: Sounds like you need to declare that @LocationID variable that is present in your SQL Statement. Is this from a stored procedure? Since this is crammed into a COALESCE and you don't know what the value of @LocationID is you can just swap both of the `COALESCE(@LocationID, LocationID)` bits of code with just `LocationID` and let 'er rip.

Comment: It usually runs from a stored procedure but right now I'm running it straight from SSMS

Comment: `Between '2018-10-23 AND 2018-10-25'` - is that a typo in your post? It should be `Between '2018-10-23' AND '2018-10-25'` (AND is a keyword and both dates are separate values)

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have to define `LocationId` first.
Try add in front of your codeblock:

```
DECLARE @LocationID DATATYPE
SET @LOCATION ID = VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a declaration for @locationID before running the main query like:

```
declare @LocationId int = 10;
SELECT * FROM dbo.vwAlarmAssetGroupLocationReport
WHERE (LocationID = CAST(COALESCE(@LocationId, LocationId) AS uniqueidentifier) OR TopLocationId = CAST(COALESCE(@LocationId, TopLocationId) AS uniqueidentifier))
AND DateCreated Between '2018-10-23' AND '2018-10-25'
AND AssetGroupId = '8E99BAFB-739A-E411-B54B-40F2E9985B7A'
ORDER BY DateCreated
```

ALso please notice that the AND keyword after BETWEEN keyword should not be in the quotes.